# Magento 2: add left sidebar in cms page

Tags: magento2, layout

I try to define the new design layout and call the left sidebar in cms pages.
[image]

What I do:
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/layout01/Magento_Theme/layout/layouts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="customer_services">
        <label translate="true">Customer Service Page</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

Now:
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/layout01/Magento_Theme/page_layout/customer_services.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="main" htmlClass="column main col-md-10"/>
    <referenceContainer name="columns">
    <container name="col-sidebar" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-2" before="main">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="customer.services.menu" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">customer-services-menu</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="customer.services.block2" after="customer.services.menu">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">customer-services-block2</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Now I created a new block with ID:

```
customer-services-menu
```

After refreshing cache Still I did not see any new design layout:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call static block on page

Try below code :

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```

If you want to call in phtml file :

Try below code :

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Cms\Block\Block::class)->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

Your xml file code should be :

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="yourblockid">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">yourblockid</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

At Last, if you want to call phtml with your block in cms page:

Try below code :

```
{{block class="Magento\Modulename\Block\Blockname" template="Magento_Modulename::templatefilename.phtml"}}
```

Refer to this link for more details - https://chetansanghani.wordpress.com/2015/11/20/magento2-display-static-block-in-phtml-file-cms-page/

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the below code

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/page_layou/customer_services.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="main" htmlClass="column main col-md-10"/>
    <referenceContainer name="columns">
        <container name="col-sidebar" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-2" before="main">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="customer.services.menu" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">customer-services-menu</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="customer.services.block2" after="customer.services.menu">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">customer-services-block2</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

check now your **Customer Service Page** is showing

[image]

In frontend also applied **Customer Service Page**

[image]